# Android: how to draw ImageButton as pressed until it loses focus?

Tags: android, imagebutton

Once pressed, I would like an ImageButton to continue to draw as if it was pressed until something else is touched.  Is there a way to do this short of extending the ImageButton to control how it is drawn, and adding a focus listener to monitor if it loses focus?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selectors objects instead of bitmaps to give the desired effect in image buttons

More on this here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: hmm. looks promising, but these look to be so that i can designate the bitmap to be used for pressed, focused, etc. What i'd really like to do is just make it paint the default "pressed" orangey background when it is focused.

Comment: figure out the default ids for the pressed and put them in your new selector object and have fun. Unfortunately there is no partial work around